# git-svn on subset of large svn repo

Tags: svn, git-svn, hgsubversion

repo layout:
a/1
a/2
a/3
...
b/1
b/2
...
c/1
c/2
...

git-svn works perfect for me if I work on 1 svn repo subdir.
But right now I'm facing the need to work on several subdirs (like, a/1, a/2, and b/1), and there's much shit in repo besides them.
I've managed to write a regexp for this, but git-svn with --ignore-paths seems to check *each* file's name against this regexp, instead of skipping entire folders, so it's too slow. /* Probably I should file a bug report about this */

So -- any ideas of handling this? If some Mercurial svn agent can do selective clones, it's OK too, but I'd better stick with git.
My another idea was some selective svn proxy, but I haven't succeeded in googling anything like that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So far i have not seen a good way to attain this.

Have you considered running:
git svn clone yourhost.com/a/1
git svn clone yourhost.com/a/2
....

That should cut down on the transfer,
then you stitch the information together through git merge (into one repository)
and/or thought git submodules.

Comment: Yes, I have considered this. It disables you from committing all the changes at once. Not a big deal, but kind of inconvenient.